# Magento2 : IncrementId value not resulting in an order

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, log, increment-id

I want to load the data of an order with the incremental id after placing an order. I am getting the incremental id in the data array after placing an order, but cant load any orders with it.

**My Observer:**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData();
        $incrementId = $order['increment_id'];
        $this->helper->writeShp($incrementId);
    }
```

**WriteShp():**

```
public function writeShp($incrementId){
        try {
            $this->logger->info($incrementId);
            $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
            $this->logger->info('order', array('order', $order));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
```

The following is getting logged:

> ```
> [2019-03-07 14:54:02] main.INFO: 000000040 [] []
> [2019-03-07 14:54:02] main.CRITICAL: No such entity with orderId =  [] []
> ```

The weird thing is the [ ] [ ] behind the incrementId. Could this be the problem?

I have tried this:

```
$onlyId = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $incrementId);
```

but still there would be [ ] [ ] behind the incrementid. Imploding also didn't work, it said it wasnt an array.

Comment: which event do you use? `sales_order_place_after`?

Comment: Yes that's the one! Dont want to use the checkout_onepage_succes one since not all payment methods lead to that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event `sales_order_place_after` the order you try to load isn't stored in the database at that moment. That's why `loadByIncrementId()` fails. The `save()` call comes right after that event.

So you can either take the `$order` object as it will be saved, that's the parameter passed to the observer or take a later event like `sales_order_save_after` or even `sales_order_save_commit_after` if you really want to load the data from database (for what ever reason). In both cases you will have for example the the order id.

Comment: Totally forgot! sales_order_save_after might be a better option then, but that will also get fired when an admin saves an order after it's already created right? Thats not what I want since the observer should only get fired once after an order is created.

Comment: I don't know your exact requirement but for example you can place the observer in the frontend area - in that case you will not touch any order from admin. But anyway `sales_order_save_after` might be triggered more than once in the order's lifetime even in frontend. But I'm sure you should better use that event.